# Selectmenu goes off the screen if near the edge

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

`div.ui-selectmenu-menu` goes off the screen if Selectmenu is near the right edge of the window. [This is the default Selectmenu behaviour, I guess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaWEz.png) (Similar thing happens if Selectmenu is near the bottom edge of the window.)

What I want to do is to move the `div.ui-selectmenu-menu` a bit to the left, ie. to [align it to the right edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrBzg.png) of the Selectmenu, but only if given Selectmenu is problematic (I want to keep default alignment for all the other menus).

I've come up with some kind of a solution, but it's not working 100%:
https://jsfiddle.net/rh6gjkpt/

I don't get expected behaviour first time when I open Selectmenu. When I close and open it againt, then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jQueryUi problem and it is not up to you.

### What is happening

When you create the Ui component it renders only the select box as you ee it. When you click for the first time on the component it **then** calculated the width of the elements.

This is why for the first time you see a list that overflows and then when you open it again it breaks into multiple lines.

**Before calculation *(component init)*:**
[image: init]

**After calculation *(when clicked)*:**
[image: click]

So when you calculate `rightOffsetOfAnElement` it return a "wrong" value for the first click because the dropdown isn't positioned nor sized the same.

### Solution

The hack you can use is click it twice when page load so it will invoke the calculate method:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh6gjkpt/4/)

### Recommendation

I personally wouldn't recommend using jQueryUi because it's old and it doesn't do the job as you see. Also it is really big at 250kb+ you will have better luck combining small components.
*For example tooltip [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) is 14kb and it has much more options then the jQueryUi tooltip.*

Also use [Select2](https://select2.org). Make your life easier.

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need to do is set `collision: "flip"` on the position option, like this:

```
$("select").selectmenu({
    "position": {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "flip"
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rh6gjkpt/6/